# Trouble setting the location of a jLabel with ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm very new to Java and I encountered a weird situation in my code where I'm trying to get a jPanel into which I am loading an ImageIcon to be in the top left corner regardless of the size of the Image. For some reason, my code displays the Image in the middle of the screen vertically but left-aligned horizontally.

The weirdest part is that when I used a message box for debugging, after clicking ok on the message box the image gets moved to the corner where I want it. This only works when I uncomment imo completely irrelevant line in that tells me the bounds of the jLabel after the image is drawn.

My code is the following:

```
    private void OpenWidefieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file;
        file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        BufferedImage Image1 = null;
        try {
            Image1 = ImageIO.read(file);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SMLMFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        int w = Image1.getWidth();
        int h = Image1.getHeight();
        ImageIcon imgIcon;
        imgIcon = new ImageIcon(Image1);
        jLabel1.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
        Rectangle r = jLabel1.getBounds();
        jLabel1.setIcon(imgIcon);
        r = jLabel1.getBounds();
        //SMLMFrame.infoBox(r.toString(), "TITLE BAR MESSAGE");
        jLabel1.setBounds(r);
```

So basically my main problem is moving the jLabel to the corner, but I'm actually more interested in why opening the infoBox at the end moves it.

Comment: Please provide a short runnable example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), so we also can reproduce your problem and provide a solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason, my code displays the Image in the middle of the screen vertically but left-aligned horizontally.

Swing uses layout managers to position components. Without knowing which layout manager you are using we can't tell why this is happening.

```
jLabel1.setBounds(r);
```

Manually setting the bounds of a component can temporarily change the location of a component. However, the next time the layout manager is invoked, the size/location of the component will be reset. Try, for example, to resize the frame as this will cause the layout manager to be invoked.

So the solution to your problem is to use an appropriate layout manager. Maybe a simple `FlowLayout` that is left aligned?

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.